# preg_match, should $matches be defined?

Tags: php

I see some scripts doing this:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

Is there any reason for defining the `$matches` variable before calling the function?

Or maybe is it just to avoid some IDEs to issue a undefined variable warning?

Comment: You'd only do it if $matches was set to be a reference somewhere earlier, e.g. you're re-using variables. if it was a reference elsewhere in your code, then the preg results would overwrite/destroy whatever $matches was referring to. if it's the first time you're using it, then pre-declaring is pointless. php will create it for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `preg_match` will return a `0` or `1`, based on if anything matches the regex. So, for many programs, you only want to know if something at all matched and you aren't concerned with what actually matched.

`$matches` is for when you want to know what part(s) of the string matches. That's why it's an optional argument. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (the square brackets `[]` indicate optional arguments)

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

You're right that `$matches` does not have to be defined first. IDEs don't like that (they lint for undefined variables), which would be a reason to define it.